# Is it possible to use HTTP over FTP?

Tags: internet-connection

I live in an area where internet cost is 10x more compared to my city but our district FTP, Utorrent network speed is unlimited. This means I can download files with no speed cap using FTP or UTP. There are much cheaper internet hundred miles far away. I could share internet speed from my friends who live there. So if I can convert HTTP to FTP I can have a cheaper internet. Anyone did this or some impossible idea?
Sorry, my bad I meant UTP as utorrent transfer protocol. There is no such thing as UTP.[My idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnuRr.png)

**Edit**

I have come into the conclusion that I was confused about protocols to ask a question here correctly at the first place. All I can understand is I had and still have access to the [IX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_exchange_point) that my ISP uses. Multiple ISP uses same IX to transfer data internally without using the bandwidth of the web that eventually goes to undersea cable. There is a big chance that someone else I know has ISP that connects to the same IX. I will be able transfer data to the other person faster as long as the person and myself are under same IX.

Now my question was if it's possible to use proxy/vpn like technologies to send or receive data form the Cheaper ISP with more bandwidth given on the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnuRr.png). I know it's never done before. Just wanted to know if..

I was referring to FTP as File Transfer Protocol.

Comment: Apparently what you are calling “FTP” or “UTP” is entirely different than what I know it to be. Please clarify as I can’t think of how either are related to your question.

Comment: By UTP, do you mean UDP? If UDP, then you should be able to use a VPN. Otherwise, HTTP over FTP? No. However, you could possibly create a vpn tunnel over port 21 and try to trick an unsophisticated ISP. It’s hard to say.

Comment: UTP= Unshielded Twisted Pair, FTP = Foiled Twisted Pair.

Comment: Sorry didn't check what I entered.

Comment: Sorry, but the answer to this question is 1,000,000,000% no on all levels.

Comment: On the contrary, this is **almost always possible** provided that you have another box somewhere to form the far end of your tunnel.  The primary problem at the moment is that you don't seem to be able to clearly state what the protocol you want to tunnel over is - you won't be able to do this until you figure out *what* you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry L.MOE - they're just straight up two different things (protocols) and what you're asking for is simply not possible...

[Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol)

[File Transfer Protocol (FTP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol)

A Web Server (*on the Internet/World Wide Web*) serves **web pages** to a users browser using the **HTTP** protocol.

An FTP Server/Client (*usually also connected to the Internet/World Wide Web*) transfer **files** between one another using the **FTP** protocol.

But all is not necessarily lost... with the growth of 4G and now 5G telecommunication services, sizable data plans can now be found at better rates than wired/satellite services (*in my experience*). I should know, my area doesn't even have telephone lines, but the 4G service is great - more reliable and MUCH cheaper than satellites! Combine a 4G SIM with a Wi-fi Dongle and an Omni-directional Antenna (or better a directional Yagi antenna) and you'll probably be on the interwebs at not "that" much slower speed, but likely for a bunch less money.

Just a thought - hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you. I was just thinking if there was any way to use my high-speed FTP privilege. Maybe there was a way to transfer HTTP data over FTP. I don't know much about these protocols so its fine.

Comment: What do you mean by utp? If you meant UDP, then yes, you can use a VPN (eg OpenVPN) to do this,but your question does not make much sense. You can't easily convert http to FTP because FTP or VV because FTP is a horrible protocol.

Comment: I should have asked, but I took it to mean µTP (Micro Transport Protocol), the protocol used for BitTorrents. It didn't make sense to me as UDP - why would an ISP let customers go nuts with UDP over TCP? Then again, why let them go nuts torrenting with µTP? This part of the question really isn't adding up...

Comment: this is what happens with my isp.

Comment: This answer is **severely mistaken** - tunneling one protocol through another is in fact generally possible and routinely done.  Of course you need something to talk to which is willing to convert the traffic back.  There may be specific oddball combinations which might present practical challenges to such tunneling, and specific use cases other than the one asked about where performance would be too poor to be useful, but generally it can be done.

Comment: Web pages are, essentially, just files anyway... I'd say writing a proxy to masquerade HTTP requests as FTP would be a 30 minute job – for a working prototype, at least.

Comment: Fair cop... in hindsight "simply not possible" wasn't the best choice of words, "simply not practical" is probably more accurate. Yes tunneling is common and generally a "thing", but tbh I've never come across the users requested scenario - HTTP tunneled through FTP. A proxy at his friends place could be an option too (assuming static IP's), but I've still got reservations over the practicability of this. I'm sure the OP would appreciate a more detailed answer if possible - and I'd learn something too! But for now, I'm sticking with my 4G/5G solution! :-)